# Internal Server Error 500 when sending mail to AWS SES with cakephp running on Hiawatha

Tags: php, email, cakephp, amazon-web-services, hiawatha

I'm getting "Internal Server Error 500" after the third or sometimes at the first attempt to send a mail using CakePHP 3 through AWS SES account (in production mode) running on Hiawatha server.

Here is my php code:

```
  public function sendmail()
{
    $email = new Email();
    $email->transport('SES');
    try {
        $res = $email->from(['account@example.com' => 'Name'])
              ->to(['receiver@hotmail.com' => 'Receiver'])
              ->subject('Test mail')
              ->send('some text');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->Flash->error('Error. Please, try again.');
        echo 'Exception : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
    $this->Flash->success('Ok. You will receive a confirmation mail');
    return $this->redirect('/');}
```

Here is the transport configuration

```
     'EmailTransport' => [
     'SES' => [
         'host' => 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
         'port' => 25,
         'timeout' => 60,
         'username' => 'ASDFASADQWE',
         'password' => 'FSDFDSFDSFSEREWRWERWER',
         'tls' => true,
         'className' => 'Smtp'
     ],
```

port 465 and 587 are not working at the first attemp

So, basically I can't identify if the problem came from CakePHP, AWS SES or some configuration on the server.

Thank you for any recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I stop to use cakePHP mail and setup PHPMailer, some difficulties to use compose and make it run, however at the end this is the working code that I can send many mails in a row.

```
   public function sendMailPHPMailer()
    {
      $mail = new \PHPMailer();
      $mail->isSMTP();                                      
      $mail->Host = 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';  
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
      $mail->Username = 'username'; 
      $mail->Password = 'password';
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';    
      $mail->Port = 587;                               
      $mail->From = 'mail@mail.com';
      $mail->FromName = 'cakePHP PHPMailer';
      $mail->addAddress('tomail@mail.com', 'receiver');
      $mail->isHTML(true);                               
      $mail->Subject = 'Test using PHPMailer & SES';
      $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
      $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text';

      if(!$mail->send()) {
          $this->Flash->error('error');
          echo 'Exception : ',  $mail->ErrorInfo, "\n";
          return $this->redirect('/');
        }else{
          $this->Flash->success('ok');
          return $this->redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

And with this code I can send only 3 mails with an interval of 1s then I receive an error 500.

```
    public function sendmail()
    {
        $email = new Email();
        $email->transport('SES');
        try {
            $res = $email->from(['mail@mail.com' => 'cakePHP mail'])
                  ->to(['tomail@mail.com' => 'receiver'])
                  ->subject('cakePHP & SES')
                  ->send('message via cakePHP and SES');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->Flash->error('error');
            echo 'Exception : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $this->Flash->success('ok');
        return $this->redirect('/');
}
```